# Is it legal to directly tie a campaign donation to how a US Congressman votes on a bill?

Tags: united-states

If you had a connection to a congressman, and spoke to him directly, and said vote yes (or no) on a bill and I will give your upcoming campaign $1M dollars, would that be considered legal under US law?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is *quid pro quo* corruption and/or bribery, and is a felony.

See (*inter alia*) [18 U.S.C. §201](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/201), specifically (c)(1)(A), which imposes a fine or jail to anyone who:

> directly or indirectly gives, offers, or promises anything of value to any public official, former public official, or person selected to be a public official, for or because of any official act performed or to be performed by such public official, former public official, or person selected to be a public official

Comment: Is that enforceable in practice, where, we are lead to believe, public corruption is often done via winks and nudges?  E.g., are you aware of any examples in which the quid pro quo was never explicit but still proven beyond a reasonable doubt?

Comment: This is a pretty comprehensive review: http://www.justice.gov/sites/default/files/criminal/legacy/2013/09/30/electbook-rvs0807.pdf